# UIAppearance and UIWindow

Tags: ios, uikit, uiappearance

From the reference:

> iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t
>   change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To change
>   the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view
>   from the view hierarchy and then put it back.

Can I use appearance proxy for `UIWindow` instances? How? I don't necessarily mean default, key window of the app but any future instance at least.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Lets begin with preset of `tintColor`.